# Set Locale not working for spring message code

Tags: spring-mvc, weblogic-10.x, resourcebundle

in a spring webapp i need to change locale dynamically due to db parameter.
I am using spring interceptor to check this parameter and if switch is necessary, i do the following instructions:

```
    LocaleResolver localeResolver = RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver(request);
localeResolver.setLocale(request, response, StringUtils.parseLocaleString("en_custom"));
```

Then, client_side, i check the new locale and use jQuery.i18n to retrieve the correct language file ( `messages_en.properties OR message_en_custom.properties` )

In local environment, on Tomcat and maven jetty, it works both on labels resolved with jQuery.i18n than on

On Weblogic it doesn't works on JSP (`<spring: message code..` labels ).

Any ideas?
Thanks

---

UPDATED: Issue solved!

Issue was generated from locale name used.
If i use

> en_custom

it doesn't work, but using

> en_CUSTOM

it works!

So the region part of a locale (the ones after the '_' MUST BE always with UPPERCASE.)